Time travels and car racing
I'm looking for the movie which:

is from the 80s
is probably English language
main subject was car racing when the folowing car during car racing run down the preceding one and was kicked off into air. During its flight it crash wuth the baner over the race lane
before the car crash with the banner the driver was replaced with someone else from future/past. This scene is repeated at least twice during the movie. 

